# Camtasia on Firefox (Eclipse IDE videos)

Tags: firefox, camtasia

I downloaded the 6 lesson videos for the Eclipse IDE and I am trying to view them.  I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.

When I run the .SWF files, the image does not seem to follow along with what the narrator is saying, at least in the first minute.  When I run the .HTML file, it says Camtasia needs Firefox to have JavaScript enabled and the Flash Player.  I have satisfied those requirements but I still get the same error message.

What are the problems here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to boot Windows 7 and run the .SWF file in Internet Explorer.